# Stop moving desktop with multiple Chrome windows

Tags: google-chrome, desktop

I recently have really annoying issue with Chrome.

I am using Mac OSX 10.14.5 Mojave with Chrome version 75.0.3770.142

Here is the issue. I have two Chrome windows and I put each window to each desktop like Chrome window 1 for desktop 1 and Chrome window 2 for desktop 2.

Of course each desktop has different applications like terminal, Acrobat reader etc. Say I am doing some text editing with my terminal in desktop 1 and I need to find something via Chrome in desktop 1. When I switch application via `Cmd + tab` (like usual) from terminal to Chrome, then it suddenly moves to Chrome window 2 that is in desktop 2.

All other applications is okay i.e. switching apps in desktop 1 only happen in desktop 1 (not moving desktop 2).

Does anyone have similar problem like this?

I also turned off `Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use` in mission control and quit the hole Chrome windows then do it again. But anything was helpful.

Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you specifically switch to desktop 2 instead of letting chance have a hand in it?

Comment: @Tetsujin What do you mean by specifically switching to desktop 2? I want that switching from some random apps in desktop 1 to chrome doesn't change desktop i.e. keep in desktop 1 not 2 in this case

Comment: Basically, you're breaking the Spaces paradigm. Spaces is not designed to support apps spread to multiple desktops, so cmd/tab gets a bit random. I don't really think there's a fix, although Mojave is a bit better at it than older OSes. Maybe Catalina will get it right eventually.